# Ejecutar URL sin abrir nueva ventana

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

perdonen alguno sabra como puedo ejecutar esta URL sin que me abra o redirija a nada... he trabajado ultimamente con que abra una pestaña nueva, pero ahora necesito solo unicmaente ejecutar esa ULR (Intene quitar mi variable redirect, pense que no se iba a abrir si no que solo ejecutar pero no me funciono jejejej)

mi codigo:

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("TerminarCompra", "Venta")',
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({oCliente: Cliente, IdUsuario : 2027 }),
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   success: function (data) {

                       var url = '@Url.Action("ConfirmarCotizacionPDFReport", "Venta")' +
                      "?numero=" + data.mensaje +
                       "&Destinatario=" + $("#txtCorreoElectronico").val();
                       var redirectWindow = window.load(url, '_blank');
                
                       swal("", "Cotizacion enviada", "success");
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () { },
                    error: function () { },
                    complete: function () { }
               })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ejecutar una URL sin abrirla o redirigir a ninguna página, puedes utilizar una petición AJAX. En tu código, simplemente debes cambiar la línea window.load(url, '_blank'); por $.ajax({url: url});. Esto enviará una petición a la URL especificada sin abrir o redirigir a ninguna página.

Por ejemplo:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("TerminarCompra", "Venta")',
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify({oCliente: Cliente, IdUsuario : 2027 }),
  dataType: "json",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function (data) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("ConfirmarCotizacionPDFReport", "Venta")' +
    "?numero=" + data.mensaje +
    "&Destinatario=" + $("#txtCorreoElectronico").val();
    // En lugar de abrir una nueva pestaña, enviaremos una petición AJAX a la URL especificada
    $.ajax({url: url});
    swal("", "Cotizacion enviada", "success");
  },
  beforeSend: function () { },
  error: function () { },
  complete: function () { }
})
```

Si necesitas manejar la respuesta de la petición AJAX, puedes utilizar el parámetro success para especificar una función que se llamará cuando la petición tenga éxito. Por ejemplo:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(response) {
    // Aquí puedes manejar la respuesta de la petición
  }
});
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema. ¡Suerte!

Comment: @Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, te lo agradezco.